# How to pronounce "E = mc²"

Tags: pronunciation

How do we pronounce *E = mc²*? This is a physics equation.

Comment: It's "physics".  Or is it?   (Yes, I'm about to go on a nitpicking spree, but then again, this *is* about "English Language and Usage", right?)

Comment: It is physics, yes. It comes from the plural of physic, which is an old world meaning natural things (though physics is now of course singular). Physic is also an old word for healing.

Comment: @Elendil, I agree, but then why do the Americans call it 'math' (mathematics)?

Comment: @CJM: I assume they simply knocked 'ematics' off the end, whereas the more subtle and generally better-looking Brits excised 'ematic' leaving 's' intact. ;)

Comment: Yes, it's a physics equation. For those who don't recognise it, it's the mass-energy equivalence equation from Einsteins special theory of relativity.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: I resent your implication that Brits are subtler and better-looking. ;)

Comment: @Jon Purdy: A typically blunt, colonial response! :D

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: Ah, but the colonies are filled with the most subtle and attractive of all; we are simply better at hiding it than you Brits, who wear your hearts on the outside! But, lest I inadvertently harm you with my elegant nuance and startlingly good looks, I shan't argue. :)

Comment: Here is the sound bite of Einstein stating the equation (he says "E is equal to m c-squared"):  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CC7Sg41Bp-U

Comment: @Jon Purdy: Ah yes, the famous American reserve O.o

Comment: @Guffa arguably it its more of a media soundbite. its pretty much useless in actual physics but can be derived from the much more useful E^2 = p^2c^2 +m0^2c^4

Comment: @Jon Purdy: I resemble that remark!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You read this as *E equals M C squared*, with the three letters pronounced as you would when reading the alphabet.

Comment: For a video demonstration of this pronunciation, see 1:55 onwards of:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZqUNEHYZgQ

Comment: Or here: http://www.aip.org/history/einstein/sound/voice1.mp3

Comment: @ghoppe Einstein says: "E is equal M C square".

Comment: @Hugo Yep, that's right :)

Answer (score 15):

The "=" sign is read as "equals" or "is equal to", depending on your culture.
(In the latter case, "is equal to" is such a common phrase all through school that it's typically read as one word: "izziqualtu".)

The "c<sup>2</sup>" could rarely be "c [raised] to the power of 2", but is almost always "c squared" (or "c square").

Thus, "ee equals em see square[d]" or "e is equal to em see square[d]".

Comment: @Jasper Loy: *c to the second (power)* is also (more?) common.

Comment: LOL at "izziqualtu"!

Comment: @Jimi: Heh. It's even conceivable that someone made it through school without ever resolving the "word" *izziqualtu* into three words. It was certainly very very late in my childhood that I had the epiphany that the postfix multiplication operator "zar" from our multiplication tables — as in "three one zar three", "three two zar six" (we even used to ask each other "what is seven nine zar?" and the like) — was merely "three ones are three" etc.

Comment: Ha ha ha:) +1 for "izziqualtu" and "zar". And most people I know say "two six zar twelve" and not "two sixes are twelve".:)

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, one could say

> Energy is the mass times the square of the speed of light in a vacuum.

If you are so inclined.

Answer (score 4):

If you listen to this [audio clip](http://www.aip.org/history/einstein/voice1.htm) of Albert Einstein speaking in 1947, you can hear him say it as **"E is equal M C square"** (with letters as *ee, em, see*).

But nowadays it's normally pronounced as Jasper Loy answered: *E equals M C squared*.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple you just go on speaking each word and symbol as they are.
So that makes it :
"E is equal to M C Square "

Comment: Normally, that's "Ee equals emcee squared."